# Scrape specific web data

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.seek.co.nz/jobs/in-new-zealand/#dateRange=999&workType=0&industry=&occupation=&graduateSearch=false&salaryFrom=0&salaryTo=999999&salaryType=annual&companyID=&advertiserID=&advertiserGroup=&keywords=&page=3&displaySuburb=&seoSuburb=&where=All+New+Zealand&whereId=3001&whereIsDirty=false&isAreaUnspecified=false&location=3001&area=&nation=3001&sortMode=ListedDate&searchFrom=quick&searchType="
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
#print soup.prettify()
job_title = soup("a", {"class": "job-title"})

print job_title
```

I want to pick up all the job-titles from the website.

I run the code but the result is `blank []`. I tried all the usages of `find_all()` but none work.

I am sure that the website includes the information I need.

[image: html]

Comment: The browser developer tools show the DOM as it is *now* in the browser, with all dynamic changes applied. Check if the site uses Javascript to load additional information, and look at the actual source of the page (*View Source* in the *View -> Developer* menu in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks. The site uses javascript so this cannot work. I am now testing the  selenuim to solve this problem. Will update later.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the html to see if there are any a tags with the call job_title in there. I tried doing that and did not found any. As suggested in the comment by Martijn Pieters, the browser developer tools show also the DOM created dynamically by javascript.

Comment: Thanks. The site uses javascript so this cannot work. I am now testing the  selenuim to solve this problem. Will update later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys  
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QWebPage):  

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)  

  def __init__(self, url):      
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_() 

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'https://www.seek.co.nz/jobs/in-new-zealand/#dateRange=999&workType=0&industry=&occupation=&graduateSearch=false&salaryFrom=0&salaryTo=999999&salaryType=annual&companyID=&advertiserID=&advertiserGroup=&keywords=&page=3&displaySuburb=&seoSuburb=&where=All+New+Zealand&whereId=3001&whereIsDirty=false&isAreaUnspecified=false&location=3001&area=&nation=3001&sortMode=ListedDate&searchFrom=quick&searchType='  
r = Render(url)  
html = r.frame.toHtml() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")   
job_title = soup.find("a", {"class": "job-title"})

print(job_title)
```

Out put:

```
<a class="job-title" data-bind="storeJobInformation: { currentPage: $root.pagination.currentPage, jobsCount: $root.jobs.jobs().length }, 
                                        html: name, 
                                        attr: { 
                                            target: !$root.onsiteSearch() ? '_self' : '_blank', 
                                            href: SEEK.searchResultsPage.jobDetailsActionUrl + '/' + id + '?pos=' + position + '&amp;type=' + adType() + '&amp;engineConfig=' + $root.jobs.engineConfig() + '&amp;userqueryid=' + $root.jobs.userQueryId() + '&amp;tier=' + (locationMatch === 'Exact' ? 'tier1' : (locationMatch === 'Nearby' ? 'tier2' : (locationMatch === 'Area' ? 'tier3' : 'no_tier'))) + '&amp;whereid=' + ($root.jobs.location().whereId || '')
                                        },
                                        click: $root.jobs.handleJoraAdClick" href="/job/32120592?pos=1&amp;type=promoted&amp;engineConfig=&amp;userqueryid=123949496807341226&amp;tier=no_tier&amp;whereid=3001" target="_self">Trade Assistant</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I am trying to use Qtwebkit but I have some problem when installing the QT. I am using win10/python2.7. Is is caused by something related to Compatibility?

Comment: The code above is python3.5 and  PyQt5, try install python3.5 and pip3 at first then try  pip3 install PyQt5